correct parameter to sysfs_create_files()
I was looking at an educationnal kernel module, you will find an extract below.
I have concern about the function pcd_sysfs_create_files() using pcdrv_data.device_pcd in probe function:
pcdrv_data is a global pointer. So my question is:
In the case of multiple probe calls, could pcdrv_data.device_pcd be overwritten? This would cause all sysfs files to be associated only with the most recently probed device? Otherwise, how the sysfs_remove_file() will be handled?
struct pcdev_platform_data
{
    int size;
    int perm;
    const char *serial_number;
};

/* Device private data structure */
struct pcdev_private_data
{
    struct pcdev_platform_data pdata;
    char *buffer;
    dev_t dev_num;
    struct cdev cdev;
};

/* Driver private data structure */
struct pcdrv_private_data
{
    int total_devices;
    dev_t device_num_base;
    struct class *class_pcd;
    struct device *device_pcd;
};

/* Driver's private data */
struct pcdrv_private_data pcdrv_data;

int pcd_sysfs_create_files(struct device *pcd_dev)
{
    return sysfs_create_group(&pcd_dev->kobj, &pcd_attr_group);
}

int pcd_platform_driver_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    int ret;
    struct pcdev_private_data *dev_data;
    struct pcdev_platform_data *pdata;
    struct device *dev = &pdev->dev;
    int driver_data;
    /* used to store matched entry of 'of_device_id' list of this driver */
    const struct of_device_id *match;

    dev_info(dev, "A device is detected\n");

    /* match will always be NULL if LINUX doesnt support device tree i.e CONFIG_OF is off */
    match = of_match_device(of_match_ptr(org_pcdev_dt_match), dev);
    if (match) {
        pdata = pcdev_get_platdata_from_dt(dev);
        if (IS_ERR(pdata))
            return PTR_ERR(pdata);
        driver_data = (long)match->data;
    } else {
        pdata = (struct pcdev_platform_data*)dev_get_platdata(dev);
        driver_data = pdev->id_entry->driver_data;
    }

    if (!pdata) {
        dev_info(dev,"No platform data available\n");
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    /* 2. Dynamically allocate memory for the device private data */
    dev_data = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, sizeof(*dev_data), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!dev_data) {
        dev_info(dev, "Cannot allocate memory\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    /* save the device private data pointer in platform device structure */
    dev_set_drvdata(&pdev->dev, dev_data);

    dev_data->pdata.size = pdata->size;
    dev_data->pdata.perm = pdata->perm;
    dev_data->pdata.serial_number = pdata->serial_number;

    pr_info("Device serial number = %s\n", dev_data->pdata.serial_number);
    pr_info("Device size = %d\n", dev_data->pdata.size);
    pr_info("Device permission = %d\n", dev_data->pdata.perm);

    pr_info("Config item 1 = %d\n", pcdev_config[driver_data].config_item1 );
    pr_info("Config item 2 = %d\n", pcdev_config[driver_data].config_item2 );

    /*
     * 3. Dynamically allocate memory for the device buffer using size information from the platform data
     */
    dev_data->buffer = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, dev_data->pdata.size, GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!dev_data->buffer) {
        dev_info(dev, "Cannot allocate memory \n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    /* 4. Get the device number */
    dev_data->dev_num = pcdrv_data.device_num_base + pcdrv_data.total_devices;

    /* 5. Do cdev init and cdev add */
    cdev_init(&dev_data->cdev, &pcd_fops);
    
    dev_data->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    ret = cdev_add(&dev_data->cdev, dev_data->dev_num, 1);
    if (ret < 0) {
        dev_err(dev,"Cdev add failed\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* 6. Create device file for the detected platform device */
    pcdrv_data.device_pcd = device_create(pcdrv_data.class_pcd, dev, dev_data->dev_num, NULL, "pcdev-%d", pcdrv_data.total_devices);
    if (IS_ERR(pcdrv_data.device_pcd)) {
        dev_err(dev,"Device create failed\n");
        ret = PTR_ERR(pcdrv_data.device_pcd);
        cdev_del(&dev_data->cdev);
        return ret;     
    }

    pcdrv_data.total_devices++;

    ret = pcd_sysfs_create_files(pcdrv_data.device_pcd);
    if (ret) {
        device_destroy(pcdrv_data.class_pcd, dev_data->dev_num);
        return ret;
    }

    dev_info(dev, "Probe was successful\n");

    return 0;
}


pcdrv_data.device_pcd is a global variable in stead of global pointer. Since it’s global, every new probe call will overwrite it... but if each device has its own device_pcd, and the sysfs files will be associated with the correct device. There’s no risk of overwriting device_pcd during multiple probe calls.

Your answer is confusing ..

You should use device_create_with_groups(). You will find the answer to your question when understanding the difference between two.
